Generating Sinewave with PLL
I'm trying to make a sine wave and sweep frequency near 150MHz. Since my application requires exact frequency and high stability, I'm trying to look for a PLL.
However, I cannot determine if the chip I found (like the CD4046) works for the sine wave. Also, I am stuck on frequency adjustment with these PLL chips to sweep frequency.
How can I read the specs of a PLL, and how can I lock frequency and sweep it?
edit
my question is whether sinewave output is possible on an arbitrary PLL chip like the CD4046 or ADF4360. I've considered using a DDS, but I'm reluctant because of the price, bulk, and difficulty of external adjustments. I would like to control the frequency with a single voltage signal as much as possible, since I need to generate a dozen or more RF signals simultaneously
/edit

CD4046 seems a little bit too "low" (max = 1.5 MHz) for this frequency ...

DDS would be a way to go, but at what price? You'd better buy one for +1k$

Sorry for the confusion, my question is whether sinewave output is possible on an arbitrary PLL chip like the CD4046 or ADF4360.
I've considered using a DDS, but I'm reluctant because of the price, bulk, and difficulty of external adjustments.
I would like to control the frequency with a single voltage signal as much as possible, since I need to generate a dozen or more RF signals simultaneously.


my question is whether sinewave output is possible on an arbitrary PLL chip like the CD4046 or ADF4360.

Some PLLs integrate the VCO, others don't. Especially RF PLLs tend to, and often the output of these is a square wave.
So, no, not "on an arbitrary PLL chip"; you will need to read the datasheet of all components you want to use to check whether they fit your application.

cannot determine if the chip I found (like the CD4046) works for the sine wave.

No, but not because of the wave shape, but because it's far far too slow. Datasheet lecture would have saved you! (Subtext messaging here is: you should read the datasheets.)

I've considered using a DDS,

Not great for doing frequency sweeps (i.e., chirps). Either you can feed your DDS with a new step width every single sample, or you only get stepped frequency, not a sweep. And since feeding a new value every sample is roughly as complex as directly synthesizing a chirp, I honestly don't see the use for a DDS here.
I'm not sure what you mean with

sweep frequency near 150MHz

There's two different possible interpretations of that:

you want to sweep frequencies up to nearly 150 MHz(so, for example, you want to do a sweep from 1 Hz to 148 MHz)
you want to sweep frequencies in a narrow bandwidth around 150 MHz(so, for example, you want to do a sweep from 149 MHz to 151 MHz)

1. Interpretation ("up to nearly 150 MHz")
Sweeps are physically complicated; analog oscillators that you can tune across many octaves like in the 1. interpretation are hard or impossible to build; so, you'd always to some digital control. There are a few frequency synthesizer ICs (not just "PLLs") that allow you to step in a relatively narrow frequency grid, but that's still going to be steps, it's still going to have settle times, and it's still not going to be a nice chirp.
So, two options

Use a VCO at a much higher frequency (for example, nominally running at 2.4 GHz) and pull it around there with an analog control voltage. That's easier than pulling a VCO from 0 to 150 MHz, because 150 MHz are "small" relative to 2.4 GHz. You can then just use a mixer with a fixed second oscillator to bring down the range to 0 - 150 MHz. The problem here will be finding and controlling the VCO.
Throw an FPGA and a >300 MHz DAC at the problem. Use a combination of look-up table or CORDIC cosine function implementations to generate the continuous chirp. The problem here will be high-speed digital design.
(Third option: you buy an SDR that does > 150 MHz and combines the two options above. Don't know whether you have the money at hand! But it would solve the problem in "no time")

2. Interpretation ("narrow bandwidth around 150 MHz")
That one's relatively straight forward: use whatever microcontroller, application processor, DSP or FPGA is fast enough to synthesize your bandwidth digitally (so, in the example of 149 to 151 MHz, that would be 2 MHz, needing 4 MHz sample rate), convert to analog with a DAC, and mix up with a fixed difference frequency.
